# Erro: A Conversão da Cadeia de Caracteres no Tipo 'Integer' não é Válida

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, combobox

Tenho um DataGridView que carrega todos os dados de uma tabela, todos os dados são do tipo Texto Curto no BD. Faço a chamada por uma instrução em SQL para exibir no DataGridView, até esse passo corre tudo bem, tudo é carregado e exibido perfeitamente!

O Problema é quando seleciono um registro (linha inteira), e peço para retornar este registro para um formulário que tem os respectivos campos para que eu consiga edita-los, para os campos no formulário do tipo TextBox vai tranquilo, mas o erro ocorre quando tento 
exibir o conteúdo em uma ComboBox. É nesta hora que dá o erro em anexo, e tal erro não consigo resolver.

[image: Erro VB.Net 2015]

Nesta Combobox, está restritivo 2 itens apenas, SIM e NÃO. Sem qualquer tipo de edição, somente seleção dos itens da lista.

No Módulo:

```
Public intCodigoFornecedor As Integer       ''TBL_Cadastrar_Fornecedores

No Form:
Private Sub PSelecionaFornecedor() ''Guarda o que foi selecionado  
            intCodigoFornecedor = CInt(dgvFornecedores.CurrentCell.Value.ToString())  
            Me.Dispose() ''Para esconder o Form  
    End Sub   

Private Sub PSelecionaFornecedor() ''Guarda o que foi selecionado  
        intCodigoFornecedor = CInt(CType(dgvFornecedores.CurrentRow().Cells("Codigo_Fornecedor").Value, String))  
        Me.Dispose() ''Para esconder o Form  
    End Sub
```

Já tentei destas 2 formas e não consigo resolver, alguém sabe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O erro acontece pois você esta tentando fazer a conversão da palavra "SIM" para int.

Te aconselho a fazer um if:

`if dgvFornecedores.CurrentRow().Cells("Codigo_Fornecedor").Value = "SIM" then
     intCodigoFornecedor = 1
 else
     intCodigoFornecedor = 0
 end if`

Dai basta usar a logica que você necessita.

Comment: Certo! Muito Obrigado! Deu Certo!

Comment: Por nada. Poderia marcar como resposta correta.